# Sample space reduction

Tags: probability

At a Foreign Languages school, $40$ people speak English, $32$ speak Spanish, $20$ speak French, $12$ speak English and Spanish, $8$ speak English and French, $6$ speak Spanish and French, $2$ speak $3$ languages and 12 do not speak any language . Randomly choosing a person from this group, and knowing that they speak French, what is the probability that this person also speaks English and Spanish?

**Attempt:**

We know there is a total of $\displaystyle \left(40-18 \right)+ \left(32 -16 \right) + \left(20-12 \right)+ \left(12-2 \right)+\left(8-2\right)+\left(6-2\right)+2 =80$. Since we already know that the person can speak French, I think there will be a reduction of the sample space to $80-20=60$. Knowing that the number of people who like Spanish and English is $12$, we have the probability that they like both English and Spanish will be $$\frac{12}{60}$$.

But the answer is $\frac{1}{100}$. Where is my error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t think either answer is correct. There are $20$ French-speakers, and $2$ of them also speak English and Spanish. Therefore the probability that a randomly chosen one of the $20$ French-speakers is also one of the two who speaks English and Spanish is $${2\over20}={1\over10}.$$.